# What happens when I call restartLoader for an AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, asynctaskloader, android-bundle

Per the documentation, when I call restartLoader on the LoaderManager, the Bundle is delivered to my loader. Will someone please show how I might read that Bundle on the side of the loader? I hear mention of a constructor, but I am not seeing it quite yet. A very short code snippet will suffice.

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/LoaderManager.java#648

Comment: Restart loader takes 3... Bundle is passed to third parameter's (callback) creation method... Or second... I don't have whole android's documentation in my memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think it delivers a call to `onCreateLoader` so that you may use the bundle as you which, such as passing it to the constructor of your Loader implementation.

```
@Override 
public Loader<List<MyItem>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args){
   MyLoaderTask task = new MyLoaderTask(getActivity(),args); 
  return task;
 }
```